# Nginx location prefix issue

Tags: nginx

I noticed in my error logs that some requests for favicon.??? are looking for the file in various directories (not root). I used "grep" and checked my server files and all meta tags, etc - and they all point to /favicon.ico

So I solved this issue by doing this :

```
location ~* favicon\.(.*) {
    expires   365d;
    etag      on;
    try_files /favicon.ico =404;
}
```

What I would like to do is use the following prefix so my other regexp locations are not searched :

```
location ^~ favicon\.(.*)
```

However, that does not work and never matches, even for /favicon.??? requests.

Is it possible to use the "^~" prefix and still have it match for "favicon.???" in ANY directory request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^~` modifier affects the behaviour of *prefix locations*. It is **not** a *regex location*.

To make your `location ~* favicon\.` match before your other regex locations, simply make it the first regex location encountered in the `server` container.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas how many regex locations one can have in a server block before it starts to impact performance?